# How to call stored procedure by using PHP and SQL Server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2008 with PHP. I want to call a stored procedure in PHP.

Please guide me.

Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

read [mssql_execute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-execute.php)

```
$conn = mssql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mssql_select_db('somedb', $conn);

// Call a simple query
$result = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM sometable', $conn);

// Release the result resource
mssql_free_result($result);

// Then execute the procedure
$proc = mssql_init('some_proc', $conn);
$proc_result = mssql_execute($proc);

// Etc...
mssql_free_statement($proc);
```

**EDIT**

read [odbc_exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php)

```
$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);
$exec = odbc_exec($conn, "CALL storedProc()");
```

and a very nice example from the php.net docs [odbc_execute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php):

> **Examples**
>
> Example #1 [odbc_execute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php) and
>   [odbc_prepare()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php) example In the
>   following code, $success will only be
>   TRUE if all three parameters to myproc
>   are IN parameters:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;
$stmt    = odbc_prepare($conn, 'CALL myproc(?,?,?)');
$success = odbc_execute($stmt, array($a, $b, $c));
```

> If you need to call a stored
>   procedure using INOUT or OUT
>   parameters, the recommended workaround
>   is to use a native extension for your
>   database (for example, mssql for MS
>   SQL Server, or oci8 for Oracle).

Comment: I am using odbc_connect.Is it possible to work with SP when using odbc connection.???

Comment: I got it.  Thanks for your valuable supports :)