# passing parameters to stored procedure SQL server from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, sqlsrv

i want to pass my params into stored procedure in SQL server but it seems like i can't do this nicely

this is my php code for executing procedure in SQL server

```
$area = $_GET['area'];
$SQL = "Read_Location_Area";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL);
```

and this is the script for SQL server procedure

```
USE [DP_Rozakana]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Read_Location_Area]
as
BEGIN
select * from Locations where Areas = '$area'
END
```

finally the sql response for searching data from "Locations" table where Areas like $area(string), not a value from PHP

Comment: you need to pass a parameter to the procedure. use [sqlsrv_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) in php and your procedure should have a parameter which should be used internally

Comment: First learn how to [create a stored proceedure with parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

Comment: probably a duplicate of ["How to call stored procedure by using PHP and SQL Server"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344609/how-to-call-stored-procedure-by-using-php-and-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Then learn how to [call a stored proceedure with parameters](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Executing-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedures-With-PHP/4/)

Comment: @SouthL Probably not as that does not talk about parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should check official [SQLSRV Driver API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc296152.aspx%20SQLSRV%20Driver%20API%20Reference), you can find all answers about `sqlsrv` library.

Now answering your question,

Your `$SQL` string should be like `"{CALL [dbo].[Read_Location_Area]}"`.

However, you will pass a parameter to the procedure, so your procedure should be:

```
USE [DP_Rozakana]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Read_Location_Area]
as
    @area NVARCHAR(MAX) -- type of Areas column
BEGIN
    select *
    from   Locations
    where  Areas = @area
END
```

Then in php, your code eventually looks like:

```
$area = $_GET['area'];
$params = array(
    array($area, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
);
$SQL = "{CALL [dbo].[Read_Location_Area](?)}";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL, $params);
```

After these steps you should be ready to fetch results.